# How to "unlock" Ninjascript drawn object so user can change anchor points?

Tags: c#

I have a basic strategy coded example to which I can further add to as needed, but can't solve how to manually edit anchor points via mouse after the strategy has drawn the fib retracement. Extremely grateful for any help on this.  No one seems to think it's possible...

```
#region Using declarations
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using NinjaTrader.Cbi;
using NinjaTrader.Gui;
using NinjaTrader.Gui.Chart;
using NinjaTrader.Gui.SuperDom;
using NinjaTrader.Gui.Tools;
using NinjaTrader.Data;
using NinjaTrader.NinjaScript;
using NinjaTrader.Core.FloatingPoint;
using NinjaTrader.NinjaScript.Indicators;
using NinjaTrader.NinjaScript.DrawingTools;
#endregion

//This namespace holds Strategies in this folder and is required. Do not change it. 
namespace NinjaTrader.NinjaScript.Strategies
{
    public class FibRetraceWorkingAdjustFibLevels : Strategy
    {
        // create a variable to hold our Fib Retracement
        private FibonacciRetracements FR1;
        // variables to hold price level values
        private double FiftyPercentLevel;
        private double HundredPercentLevel;
        private double ZeroLevel;
        private double NineteenPercentLevel;
        private double EightyPercentLevel;
        
        protected override void OnStateChange()
        {
            if (State == State.SetDefaults)
            {
                Description                                 = @"Enter the description for your new custom Strategy here.";
                Name                                        = "FibRetraceWorkingAdjustFibLevels";
                Calculate                                   = Calculate.OnBarClose;
                EntriesPerDirection                         = 1;
                EntryHandling                               = EntryHandling.AllEntries;
                IsExitOnSessionCloseStrategy                = true;
                ExitOnSessionCloseSeconds                   = 30;
                IsFillLimitOnTouch                          = false;
                MaximumBarsLookBack                         = MaximumBarsLookBack.TwoHundredFiftySix;
                OrderFillResolution                         = OrderFillResolution.Standard;
                Slippage                                    = 0;
                StartBehavior                               = StartBehavior.WaitUntilFlat;
                TimeInForce                                 = TimeInForce.Gtc;
                TraceOrders                                 = true;
                RealtimeErrorHandling                       = RealtimeErrorHandling.StopCancelClose;
                StopTargetHandling                          = StopTargetHandling.PerEntryExecution;
                BarsRequiredToTrade                         = 20;
                // Disable this property for performance gains in Strategy Analyzer optimizations
                // See the Help Guide for additional information
                IsInstantiatedOnEachOptimizationIteration   = true;
                // initialize variables for price level values to zero
                EightyPercentLevel                          = 0;
                NineteenPercentLevel                        = 0;
                HundredPercentLevel                         = 0;
                ZeroLevel                                   = 0;
            }
            else if (State == State.Configure)
            {
            }
        }
        protected override void OnBarUpdate()
        {
            // check to see if there enough bars to check the last 200 for the high and low
            // if not, do not process further
            if(CurrentBar < 200)
                return;
            
            // create variables to hold highest and lowest prices of the last 100 bars
            double highPrice;
            double lowPrice;
            
             // store the highest bars ago value
            int highestBarsAgo = HighestBar(High, 200);
 
            //evaluate high price from highest bars ago value
            highPrice = High[highestBarsAgo]; 
            
             // store the highest bars ago value
            int lowestBarsAgo = LowestBar(Low, 200);
             
             //evaluate high price from highest bars ago value
            lowPrice = Low[lowestBarsAgo]; 
            
            // draw the fib retracement and save our Fibonacci to a variable so we can easily access its price levels
            FR1 = Draw.FibonacciRetracements(this, "MyRetracement", false, 0, highPrice, -10, lowPrice); 
            
            
            // loop through price levels and get values for 0, 19, 80 and 100 percent levels
            foreach (PriceLevel p in FR1.PriceLevels)
            {
                if (p.Value == 100)
                    HundredPercentLevel = p.GetPrice(FR1.StartAnchor.Price, FR1.EndAnchor.Price - FR1.StartAnchor.Price, true);
                if (p.Value == 19.1)
                    NineteenPercentLevel = p.GetPrice(FR1.StartAnchor.Price, FR1.EndAnchor.Price - FR1.StartAnchor.Price, true);
                if (p.Value == 80.9)
                    EightyPercentLevel = p.GetPrice(FR1.StartAnchor.Price, FR1.EndAnchor.Price - FR1.StartAnchor.Price, true);
                if (p.Value == 0)
                    ZeroLevel = p.GetPrice(FR1.StartAnchor.Price, FR1.EndAnchor.Price - FR1.StartAnchor.Price, true);
            }
            //if the close price crosses above the Nineteen percent level and we are flat, enter long and 
            //set a stop loss at 10 ticks below and a profit target at the 80.9 percent level
            if(CrossAbove(Close, NineteenPercentLevel, 1) && Position.MarketPosition == MarketPosition.Flat)
            {
                SetStopLoss(CalculationMode.Ticks, 20);
                SetProfitTarget(CalculationMode.Price, EightyPercentLevel);
                EnterLong();
            }
            // otherwise, if the close price crosses below the 80 percent level and we are flat, enter short and
            // set a stop at 10 ticks above and a profit target at the 19 percent level
            else if(CrossBelow(Close, EightyPercentLevel, 1) && Position.MarketPosition == MarketPosition.Flat)
            {
                SetStopLoss(CalculationMode.Ticks, 20);
                SetProfitTarget(CalculationMode.Price, NineteenPercentLevel);
                EnterShort();
            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Only have limited PHP experience--no C#--, so trying to cut and hack my thru it to no avail.  If there's a superstar out there who can show me the way, I'd love to hear it. Many thanks in advance.